# this is the first time **I visit** you

Tags: future-tense

Hi my teacher (native) told me to find the solution for the problematic part of this sentence (in bold).

"I’ve almost forgotten to mention that this is the first time **I visit** you."

(Short explanation the visit time is tomorrow morning.)

I have some guesses, but not sure at all please help:

Since it relates for the future I would use the:

I'm going to visit you.
or I'm visiting you.

(I will visit you - seem less applicable her for me, since he time was agreed earlier.)

On the other side I'm not sure if the tense is the problem....

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The tense is the problem.

Native speaker of English, and I'm not sure what the formal reasons for these things are called, but this is what seems right to me:

The correct way to phrase this is "This is the first time I will visit you", "This will be the first time I'm visiting you", or "This will be the first time I visit you", if you're talking about a visitation in the future. If the visitation is happening in the present, the correct way to say it is "This is the first time I have visited you."

"This is the first time I'm going to visit you" would also be correct, but it has a slightly different connotation due to the different verb ("going to visit" vs "visit"), implying a less formal visit - you might go to visit a friend at their house, but you visit your client's office.

Comment: Dear Nick, Really thanks for your answer, I found it very useful. It was my guess to, but I was not sure. Thanks again, Szabolcs